# Grabbing printed statements from console C++

Tags: c++, spdlog

I have two loggers in my program. One that I made inside a gui, and one that is super complicated but very well designed and prints to the console. I am trying to get the output from the nice console logger to the rendered one. I have tried everything under the sun to get this to work but I can't seem to figure it out (due to my lack of understanding of the code from the other logger(spdlog).) My conclusion is that taking the logs directly from what is printed is the best way to do this but I can't find online anyone asking how to do this. I have seen a few questions but they just post code as an answer and don't really explain what is going on. **My question:** Is there a way to grab printed statements from the console and what are the performance issues/complications that come with doing something like this.

For example, if i do `std::cout << "hello!" << std::endl;` or some printf statement, I want to be able to further down in the code be able to grab "hello!"

Comment: Why? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you need to "grab" the old output later in the program?

Comment: As for possible solutions (or rather workaround since you can't really "grab" terminal or console output), just save the output internally?

Comment: If you have the information you're logging... just display it in your GUI directly too instead of trying to do something as bizarre-sounding and convoluted as that?

Comment: This question could be much simpler: How do one show log written using spdlog in both a GUI and in the console?

Comment: I'd recommend something different. Wrap the output with some custom method that also stores any entries you try to print. You can then easily pull them out when necessary from however you store it.

Comment: You could create your own "tee" output stream that writes the output to somewhere, then `cout`.  Search the internet for "c++ cout tee".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am going to look further into this but this seems to be on the right path for what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My conclusion is that taking the logs directly from what is printed is the best way to do this but I can't find online anyone asking how to do this.

Consoles nowadays are terminal emulators. The original terminals' output went to printers and couldn't be (easily) read back.

Application's `stdout` and `stderr` (console) streams are write-only. Moreover, in Windows and Unix/Linux you can pipe your program's (console) output (either or both `stderr` and `stdout`) into another application with `|` (pipe) that creates a pipe IPC between `stdout` of your application and `stdin` of another one. That IPC pipe is write-only, your application cannot possibly read back from it.

You may be able to get access to the contents of the frame buffer of Windows `cmd.exe` that controls its Windows console window, but that won't be the verbatim byte-exact copy of data you wrote into `stdout` because of the [escape sequences interpreted by Windows console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

If `stdout` is redirected into a file you can re-open that file for reading, but there is no portable way to re-open that file.

In other words, there is no portable way to read console output back.

---

> I have tried everything under the sun to get this to work but I can't seem to figure it out (due to my lack of understanding of the code from the other logger(spdlog).

I bet you haven't tried reading `spdlog` documentation, in particular [logger with multi sinks](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog#logger-with-multi-sinks---each-with-different-format-and-log-level). A sink is an output abstraction, which implementation can write into a file, memory or both. What you need is attach your own sink to `spdlog` that prints into your UI.

Derive your sink from [`base_sink`](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/v1.x/include/spdlog/sinks/base_sink.h#L19) and implement abstract member functions:

- `virtual void sink_it_(const details::log_msg &msg) = 0;` to print into the `UI`, and,
- `virtual void flush_() = 0;` to do nothing.

Then attach one object of your sink class to that `spdlog`.